# "Attempt to execute script as function" error - Empty MEX folder after compiling

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vlfeat

this is my first time using Matlab & vl_feat library. I installed vl_feat library and added the library path to Matlab path using *addpath(genpath())* command.

But when I try to execute ***vl_sift*** function, it gives error "Attempt to execute SCRIPT vl_sift as function". I tried it many ways to figure out cause of that error. I compiled the library files to generate **mex** folder in "VLFEATROOT/toolbox". But the folder is empty. IS it the cause of this error. If, it is, how to generate the contents of the folder to rectify the error.

Comment: The above link I referenced is for the same error.  The basic premise is that you don't have `mex` set up.  Look at the link to figure out how to set up mex, then compile the libraries for use.

Comment: I compiled the libraries, but it generated only empty MEX folder. So, I had to download binaries and install them.

Comment: Good!  Glad it worked!